# Laravel 5.4 - npm run watch

Tags: compilation, sass, laravel-5.4

I've recently created a fresh Laravel 5.4 project.

In order to run Laravel mix, I did `npm install` and then `npm run watch`, but I ended up getting a bunch of errors and a generated npm-debug file.

How can I fix this?

**Solution:**

Node was outdated, so I did:

1. `nvm install stable`
2. `nvm use stable`
3. Delete the node_modules folder (if you have it)
4. `npm install`
5. Now run `npm run watch` again and everything should work accordingly.

Comment: Hard to say, you haven't post any error here. Are you sure you are not using quite old version of npm?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I'm updating the question right now!

Comment: it doesnt help for me

Comment: Make sure you get a fresh Laravel 5.4 install, do what I wrote here above (except step 3) and it should work. If not, what kind of error do you get?